# Have started to do something OR be starting to do something?

Tags: grammar

I have come across such sentences many times but it is difficult to understand the difference between these two types.

Examples:

*"It has started to rain."* **OR** *"It is starting to rain."*

*"I have started to hate iPhones."* **OR** *"I'm starting to hate iPhones."*

Is there any difference?

Comment: Present perfect vs present continuous - both are grammatical. Which you pick depends on what you want to express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It has started to rain" indicates that it started raining at some indefinite point in the past, whereas "It is starting to rain" implies that the rain started when the person said this sentence.

The same goes with the second example.
"I have started to hate iPhones" - you started hating them at some point in the past.
"I'm starting to hate iPhones" - you are starting to hate them right now.